# Method to read all outgoing HTTP responses android

Tags: android, httpresponse

I'm trying to see if it's possible to check outgoing HTTP and respond with my own response. E.g. someone goes on their browser types "**www.aaa.com**" then my background process can return a different response that's already saved, perhaps some family friendly page. so **"aaa -> my process -> some safe content"**

Thanks!!

Comment: you'd need a proxy for that.

Comment: and anyway, you won't be able to return much response for an https request (unless you install a root cert and spoof certificates)

Comment: @njzk2 Sorry but I think you're wrong in both cases.

Comment: @m0skit0: with a little more detail: if you setup the device to use your proxy, then, yes, you can intercept requests and return whatever. In the case of https connection, there is an extra step, installing a root certificate on the device to make it accept your responses. (Though in the case of google domains, the certificates are pinned, so that won't work.). The proxy can be installed directly on the device, afaik. You'll have noticed that this require a configuration on the device, that is usually done by the user, or through the parameters of a dhcp.

Comment: @njzk2 Ok I see what you mean. But you don't need a proxy if you can hook directly into the TCP/IP stack. In any case, the strategy is a classic man-in-the-middle.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but only in a rooted device.

Comment: Do you have a link to some open source code or what classes to start looking at?

Comment: I highly doubt you can use Android API for this. You would have to access the Linux kernel and hook into the TCP/IP stack. Something similar to what [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/) does. Btw, this smells malware/virus.

Comment: I know that's what some of my friends said, but i promise it's not (if that means anything), recent college grad, just trying to figure some things out. Thanks for the link!

Comment: You're welcome and I hope it is not. You can go to jail for such things (no joking).